# solana play ground - too much SOL for initial deployment and RPC error

Tags: solana-program, rust, rustc

I'm trying to deploy some program locally with solana playground, when trying to deploy the program on dev-net the initial deployment costs 4.40 SOL, and when requesting more than 1 SOL(with "solana airdrop ") I'm getting an error for requesting too much SOL,
so I've tried to deploy it on localhost, at the start it worked fine, but now I'm getting a new error: "Connection error. Please try changing the RPC endpoint from the settings.", someone is familiar with this problem?

Comment: I reported the increased cost to the play ground maintainer, maybe its a bug.

Comment: When deploying a pure rust program it's working fine, but when trying to deploy an Anchor program the deployment costs too much, I think it's indeed a bug @JonasH.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using Solana Playground with the endpoint set to `localhost`, you'll also need to have a local validator running.

You'll first need to install the [Solana CLI](https://docs.solana.com/cli/install-solana-cli-tools).
Then, in a separate terminal, run:

```
solana-test-validator
```

You'll then see an output that looks something like this:

```
Ledger location: test-ledger
Log: test-ledger/validator.log
⠂ Initializing...
⠤ Initializing...
Identity: 6HcgSmuRRvtmzAdpb8jgoH1E5oNUsPQ9gyg3Ymoef3Rq
Genesis Hash: EehH2XMFWs5osuePCyXRAoz97i6z3M9oWr3C1D7MUMUe
Version: 1.14.8
Shred Version: 40861
Gossip Address: 127.0.0.1:1024
TPU Address: 127.0.0.1:1027
JSON RPC URL: http://127.0.0.1:8899
⠒ 00:01:04 | Processed Slot: 136 | Confirmed Slot: 135 | Finalized Slot: 104 | Full Snapshot Slot: 100 | Incremental Snapshot Slot: - | Transactions: 135 | ◎499.9993300
```

With the local validator running, you'll then be able to use Solpg with the endpoint set to `localhost`

Solpg isn't running a local validator in the browser which is why you're seeing the message: `Connection error. Please try changing the RPC endpoint from the settings.`

Regarding the devnet airdrop rate-limit, unfortunately right now there's not a way around that and you would have to wait until you can airdrop again.

To recover and reuse the SOL from a program you can use the command:

```
solana program close <program_id>
```

For example:

```
$ solana program close 7gDheEG7SXEYtFVQATWHVuZXptB9UEJ8ForrG3BesNF3

Closed Program Id 7gDheEG7SXEYtFVQATWHVuZXptB9UEJ8ForrG3BesNF3, 0.78128088 SOL reclaimed
```

Note though that you won't be able to reuse a program address that as been closed. So be careful with it.

Comment: Thank you, now the error does not occurs, but when I'm trying to deploy the program the deployment does not finish(its stuck on deployment)

Comment: Can you try run your local validator with solana-test-validator -r to reset it?